# .Net P2P solution for game developers (preferably XNA)

Tags: .net, tcp, xna, p2p, pnrp

So, the title says pretty much all.

I had tried PNRP, but I didn't find any way to make it work with TCP, only WCF (from what I understand, PNRP is made for WCF). So if all else fails, I guess I could make my game use WCF services, but I dont know how good that option is for game networking.

What I would like the most is to make TCP work like p2p (game app is both client and server), without exchanging data over some proxy server. So please tell if there is any good approach.

Thank you!